# Router makes internet go slower

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, internet-connection

I'm having some trouble with my wireless router, so I thought I'd ask. I have a TP-Link WR941N, and every once in a while it will make internet speeds slow down by different degrees. I'm supposed to have 3 Mb/s, but sometimes I'll get anything from that down to 0.2 Mb/s on a couple of particulary bad days. I'm pretty sure it's the router's fault because I've tested with an older one and it works more or less fine, and it's not the wireless because this also happens on a wired PC.

Of course, I don't expect anyone to be able to just tell me the solution with this little information. What I'd like to know is how to tell if there's a configuration issue or the thing is just faulty. I've been snooping around in the router's admin interface, but I haven't had much success. Are there configuration options that are a known cause of problems like this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the ping replies from your gateway by typing  `ping 192.168.1.1 -t`
 Change the gateway IP as per your own gateway IP and check the results. If it's consistent without any RTO(request timed out) messages, then try the same with any website. You can try to change the patch cable if the same thing happens when you use your old router.

Comment: Well, pinging the router works fine (1 ms), but I tried with a couple of websites and got an average of around 400 ms and a couple of RTOs. What does that mean? Also, sadly I can't use the old router right now, I don't have its power cable.

Comment: this might be the issue from the ISP side .... can you try pinging the websites bypassing the router, i mean by connecting your PC directly to the Modem. If that goes fine than You could try changing the wireless-channel that the router uses. Log on to your router's web-page and change the wireless channel there (remember to save any changes). Wireless laptops can automatically switch channels as required whenever it's been changed on the router, so don't worry about that side of it.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, its difficult to give an answer with the information provided.  That said -

While the router might be faulty, it seems to me much more likely that it is a memory leak.  Most off-the-shelf routers have them, and that is why so many people look towards after-market firmware like DD-WRT/OpenWRT/Tomato, which do a much better job of handling memory etc.

If you suspect the router is faulty, you might try putting a fan across it to keep it cooler and see if it works better.  This won't do anything if it is a software problem, but could well make things work if its a hardware problem and heat buildup is affecting the tolerances of the components on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this issue cause by your tplink router. I'm also using this tplink TL941N installed with DDWRT & having the same issue with u. After a while, wireless signal is degraded & intermittent disconnect. I tried a lot of setting & finally found the most stable setting.  This router has 3 antenna. Can u try to changes below setting in admin interface:-
1) your wireless antenna, try to set, use only antenna 1 & 2.
2) use wireless NG mixed with 20Mhz only. Don't use 40Mhz.
3) use only channel 6 or 5,
4) in ddwrt setting under administrator, there is TCP congestion control. Use only reno or westwood. don't use vegas or hybla.

This is the setting i used & now my TPlink working find without speed drop event i open it a month.